# Facebook Push Notification integration in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-analytics

I have gone with Facebook Push Notification integration documentation given in the following URL: [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/android).

Also integrate Facebook analytics and the given sample code in my application but I have some confusion about Facebook Push Notification:

1. Is I am able to send the push notification to all app users from My app dashboard?
2. Unable to understand Facebook Push notification just track the all app notification's data or used to generate the notification about new features about the app?

I expect actual behavior Of Facebook Push Notification like FCM or GCM.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can send to all users by creating a segment based on the 'App Launch' event (or any other event you expect all sessions to emit). At present Push Campaigns search range is the last 30 days, so you can only target users who launched in the last 30 days (the Analytics for Apps team is investigating extending this window).

Comment: In second question I just want to know that,Is Facebook In App Notification is used to notify all your app users about the updated functionality in app or want to share some extra things about app?